# Does it make sense to use Apollo Client for server side queries?

Tags: caching, next.js, server-side-rendering, apollo-client

I'm currently working on an existing Next.js project that heavily relies on server-side rendering (SSR) and GraphQL (GQL). The project utilizes Apollo Client, but only for performing queries (`client.query`) on the server side. Here is the current configuration:

```
export const client = new ApolloClient({
  name: 'my-apollo-client',
  link: from([errorLink, httpLink]),
  ssrMode: typeof window === 'undefined',
  errorPolicy: 'all',
  connectToDevTools: true,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  defaultOptions: {
    watchQuery: {
      fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
    },
    query: {
      fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
      errorPolicy: 'all',
    },
  },
});
```

and a typical usage of the client looks is to perform server side queries to a remote system and return the data. for example, a route at `/page/api/my-page` mostly does this:

```
  const { data, errors } = await  client.query(options)
  res.status(200).json(data);
```

In this specific use case, I would like to understand if Apollo Client is providing any additional functionality beyond query execution. Does it still utilize the `InMemoryCache` on the server-side, or is it mainly used for query execution? I want to ensure the project team correctly utilizing Apollo Client.